# Permission denied error while starting hue (supervisor)

Tags: python, hadoop, hue

I am trying to install hue with the tar ball. The make process went smoothly.
While running ./supervisor to start hue, am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/bin/hue", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('desktop==2.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'hue')()
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/manage_entry.py", line 60, in entry
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/management/commands/beeswax_server.py", line 99, in handle_noargs
    os.execve(bin, args, env)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
(515) *** Controller starting at Thu Aug 29 04:16:14 2013
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/bin/hue", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('desktop==2.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'hue')()
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/manage_entry.py", line 60, in entry
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/management/commands/beeswax_server.py", line 99, in handle_noargs
    os.execve(bin, args, env)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
Should start 1 new children
Controller.spawn_children(number=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/bin/hue", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('desktop==2.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'hue')()
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/manage_entry.py", line 60, in entry
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/management/commands/beeswax_server.py", line 99, in handle_noargs
    os.execve(bin, args, env)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/bin/hue", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('desktop==2.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'hue')()
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/manage_entry.py", line 60, in entry
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/hduser/huef/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/management/commands/beeswax_server.py", line 99, in handle_noargs
    os.execve(bin, args, env)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
(515) *** Controller exiting
```

The supervisor.log files says beeswaxserver is stopped.

Comment: Beeswax will try to start as a 'hue' user and will need permissions to write logs. The group and particular [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/hue-user/yiFiH1E0LM4) has more details.

Comment: @RomainRigaux how to start hue as the logged in user rather than 'hue' user (or) how do i assign permissions to the 'hue' user?

Comment: tried changing the user in supervisor.py, still it gives me the same error.